# Reverse Engineer Instagram HTTP request

Tags: encryption, decode, reverse-engineering

I intercepted an HTTP request originating from Android to Instagram when I creating account. Here the post data that is sent to the instagram:

```
e95cef1c47aa4c85ee7555403af92acb80aca9266e8edf77a7fb75b37795c735 {"allow_contacts_sync":"true","sn_result":"API_ERROR:+null","phone_id":"7520e5f4-b4a6-4bd9-a445-972641476fde","_csrftoken":"JlMrKwuiXF6pPB5q98Srx2TZR1MrKCfe","username":"michaelabramobics2","first_name":"Michael","adid":"dac68c0e-4307-4753-8c07-3ea2c26187dd","guid":"fa13e631-1663-49cf-a507-e62dbb03012b","device_id":"android-4d0577bf20b57285","email":"michaelabramobics2@gmail.com","sn_nonce":"bWljaGFlbGFicmFtb2JpY3MyQGdtYWlsLmNvbXwxNTI2NzM1Nzk4fBgiGpUFAo8qZWzGlVPG02r9zOXztwLQnQ==","force_sign_up_code":"","waterfall_id":"52d43d05-7cac-468a-8b10-2f2499eb7cf2","qs_stamp":"","password":"123456789"}
```

How I can decode this parameter?

```
"sn_nonce":"bWljaGFlbGFicmFtb2JpY3MyQGdtYWlsLmNvbXwxNTI2NzM1Nzk4fBgiGpUFAo8qZWzGlVPG02r9zOXztwLQnQ=="
```

Base64 decoding returns:

```
michaelabramobics2@gmail.com|1526735798|"*elƕSjН
```

Email|Unixtime| and ?

What is the last value? How can I find out what encoding it is?

I will be very grateful for help.

Comment: It could just be, in fact, a random 24-byte nonce. You will have to more reverse engineering to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nonce is a number used once. Generally the nonce however consists of bytes, and they are often random bytes. It depends on the protocol if it is used a number or if the nonce is just binary data. It is is used as a number it is likely a statically sized, unsigned, big- or sometimes little endian number. But most often the nonce consists of random bytes.

Random bytes, or course, will not display as well as the mail address or the Unix time. Because the bytes are not encoded text, decoding it will generally result in garbage. If the decoded text is Unicode, or if there are unprintable characters then the result is generally shorter than you would expect as bytes are combined or left out entirely.

In hexadecimals the last part reads (converted using the [tomeko.net online decoder](http://tomeko.net/online_tools/base64.php?lang=en):

```
18221A9505028F2A656CC69553C6D36AFDCCE5F3B702D09D
```

which looks fairly random to me, it's certainly not text in any encoding. The 24 bytes are also a common length for cryptographically secure nonces, keys and such, so that would strengthen the assumption that this is a random nonce.